# iView not defined error while trying to import it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iview

I'm trying to import iView UI on my VueJS project with Webpack inside main.js.

`import iView from 'iview'`

Then:

`Vue.use(iView)`

And console shows up an error saying

`Uncaught ReferenceError: iView is not defined`

I added iview plugin by doing `npm i iview -D` on my project.

Why this isn't working? Any ideas? Maybe some package.json issues? whenever i run `npm run dev` it compiles everything fine, no errors, no warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after some hours of attempts, I found out I had two ways of including this lib.

By either doing:
`import iView from 'iview/dist/iview'`

This one would throw a warning about types not defined for this, but if you do it like so:

`const iView = require('iview')`

It will work like a charm! Hope this helps to anyone who's under the same situation I was.